# Play store apps details for jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I need help , how to get the play store game details like version, game name etc in jquery.I didn't get any idea to do this. Please help me to solve.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, Google is not providing such API at the time of writing. However, other services (usually paid) exist. These services will continiously harvest app information and provide summaries in an easy-to-access fashion.

One of those services is **apptweak.io**, they also provide 100 free requests on a monthly basis. Good luck!